# Deleting log4net logs older than n days from Auto scaled beanstalk Instances

Tags: .net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, log4net, amazon-elb, log4net-configuration

In our AWS environment,  Log4net is used for logging exceptions from Auto scaled Beanstalk IIS env behind an elastic Load balancer.  There are also worker instances and CodeDeploy service used.

Both Worker instances and Beanstalk instances write logs using log4net to udp stream as well as log files.  Rolling by date and size is possible. rotating/deleting logs older than n days is not possible in log4net. This is pending for years: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-367

Due to Auto scaling, using batch file to delete log file solder than n days is not possible for me.  What option Do I have to delete the older logs from the hosts?

**UPDATE# 1**

How about this??

```
commands:
  0_mkdir:
    command: mkdir C:\\scripts\\

  1_create_script:
    file: C:\\scripts\\delAppLogs.bat
    content: |
      forfiles /p "C:\AppLogs" /s /m *.* /D -30 /C "cmd /c del @path"

  2_runSched_delAppLogs:
    command: SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Delete Logs" /TR "c:\scripts\delAppLogs.bat" /ST 23:55 /RU SYSTEM
```

**Update# 2** 
use switch /RU on SchTasks for running scripts non interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ebextensions to customize the server and create a scheduled task that cleans up old logs.

Create a yaml `init.config` file inside a folder called `.ebextensions` in your web application root. Also add a bat/ps file to do the deletion with your application (or download one from s3) that set the contents of yaml as follows:

```
commands:
  00-log-cleanup:
    command: SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Delete Logs" /TR "c:\myapp\deletelogs.bat" /ST 23:55
```

Read more about ebextensions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html).
Read about scheduled tasks utility [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: check Update#1.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi - that should do nicely! Have you tried it out? BTW you picked up that I used the wrong header in my yaml example which I will update. One thing though - I would change job schedule to run sooner so you can verify its working.

Comment: Im testing the scheduled task on a normal instance with the forfiles command. will then transfer to the EB.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Amogh how did testing go?

Comment: Very Well for the forfiles, I also added some Send-MailMessage to have a list of files sent as an alert.  This is tested by creating a Sched task manually.  For the .ebextensions the script needs to merged by the dev guys and then it will deploy in next release..you know how this stuff works. :)  Ill keep you posted.

Comment: Not yet.  The real issue is ebextensions.  Thats still not working.

Comment: no worries - understood that it was. will stand by !